# JSESSIONID getting changed

Tags: jquery, ajax, session-cookies

I have a web app that makes heavy use of jQuery.ajax() and jQGrid. In a typical flow:

- User comes to index.html
- Does userid/password authentication via ajax
- On success, they are directed to home.html
- home.html does multiple ajax requests to populate items on the page.
- These requests are: getBriefProfile, getAuthenticatedUser and getProperties.
- The getProperties call originates from jQGrid that has to display the properties in a table.

I was running into a problem where the getProperties call on the server was not attached to the authenticated session and hence failing. Looking at XHR captures in Chrome/Safari/Firefox developer tools, I see different behavior on different browsers.

In Firefox, I see that all XHR requests submit the correct JSESSIONID cookie, except the getProperites call, which seems to not submit any cookie and thus results in a new session.

In Chrome I see strange Cookie request headers with two values of JSESSIONID:

```
Cookie:JSESSIONID=hncGp+UQxJ4X+FUEwj-gdejS; JSESSIONID=NCj6wdLOxh3zwutXEvB1UQYr; __utma=199763511.429181615.1314144361.1316197892.1316480513.20; __utmz=199763511.1314144361.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)
```

I did not even think this was possible.

Any ideas what is going wrong? All XHR requests go to the same context path on the app server.

Thanks.

-Raj

Comment: Two cookies can have the same name and co-exist in a browser if their path or domain attributes vary.

Comment: But is it right for the browser to submit then both without qualifying the path? The request header above is from Chrome.